# Windows 2008 r2 showing single disk with 2 partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, dynamic

On Virtual server Windows 2008 R2 install on hyper-v 2008.

I have a two disk but they have two partition marge as single array 0 I think.

I need to convert Dynamic disk to Basic Disk but at the moment I cant do it because it has 2 partition.

Sorry I don't know how to explain this, if you see the image you will see what I mean.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9B74F2B701A14DD!379&authkey=!AKzjcnZypEJqfXQ&ithint=folder%2cPNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do a backup, as the partition need to be deleted to convert.

To change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk using the Windows interface

1.Back up all volumes on the disk you want to convert from dynamic to basic.

2.In Disk Management, right-click each volume on the dynamic disk you want to convert to a basic disk, and then click Delete Volume for each volume on the disk.

3.When all volumes on the disk have been deleted, right-click the disk, and then click Convert to Basic Disk.

Ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx

Comment: I was try to avoid doing that.

Comment: @maj you can try a third part application that can convert, like partition magic, but the official step is that

Comment: I have create new disk and done robocopy

Answer (score 0):

On physical disk 1 you have 2 partitions (127MB and 99.87GB) and there's a volume (D:) that is spanned on those 2 partitions.

Same for the disk2 : the volume E: is spanned across the two partitions.

You cannot convert those disks to basic without removing the spanned volumes.

So you will have to backup the content , delete the volumes, delete the partitions, revert the disks to basic, create a new partition (and a new volume) on each disk and then restore the content.

To backup the content if you are concerned about permissions on folders and so on, I suggest either robocopy or imagex (those are microsoft tools), although in most case simply copying the files on an external drive should be enough (depend on the content of the volumes).

Comment: I was try to avoid doing that.